# 'CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "node": library "libcrypto.so.3" not found

Tags: node.js, installation

In Termux (my_distro):

```
$ pkg show openssl
Package: openssl
Version: 3.0.1-1
Maintainer: @termux
Installed-Size: 6648 kB
Depends: ca-certificates, zlib
Conflicts: libcurl (<< 7.61.0-1)
Breaks: openssl-tool (<< 1.1.1b-1), openssl-dev
Replaces: openssl-tool (<< 1.1.1b-1), openssl-dev
```

openssl installed pkg:

```
openssh/stable 8.8p1-3 aarch64 [upgradable from: 8.8p1-1]
openssl-tool/stable 3.0.1-1 aarch64 [upgradable from: 1.1.1m-2]
openssl/stable 3.0.1-1 aarch64 [upgradable from: 1.1.1m-2]
```

Installation of nodejs:

```
$ pkg install nodejs-lts
Setting up nodejs-lts (16.14.0-2) ...
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "node": library "libcrypto.so.3" not found
Aborted
dpkg: error processing package nodejs-lts (--configure):
 installed nodejs-lts package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Processing triggers for man (1.14.5-3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nodejs-lts
E: Sub-process /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After that it shows now.

```
$ node
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "node": library "libcrypto.so.3" not found
Aborted

$ npm
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "node": library "libcrypto.so.3" not found
Aborted
```

Comment: `libcrypto.so.3` is part of `openssl v3` which is very new and I have no idea if any distro is  released with it, even bleeding edge. Edit your question to tell us the distro. If you have installed `openssl v3` yourself then you need to tell us. You may have to find an older verion of `nodejs-lts` which works with `openssl v1`, point the code to where the `openssl v3` devel libs are, or delete `openssl v3`.

Comment: Please edit your post and put that info there. Secondly, you have a mixed system vith both openssl v1 & v3 installed, however, you do not seem to have the v3 devel package installed. Also, if you look, you'll see you now have package conflicts. Why install v3?

Comment: My openssl Version: 3.0.1-1 is it ok?

Comment: Nope. You do not have the v3 devel package installed. Look at that word `Breaks`.

Comment: ` how to install it? `

Comment: Termux? On Android?. If you do not know how to search for and install packages, then parhaps you should not install bleeding edge systems. I assume install `libssl3.0-dev`, but I have no real idea.

Answer (score 31):

`openssl-tool` may not be installed if you are running latest termux

Try running:

```
apt upgrade && apt update
apt install openssl-tool
```

Comment: Why do I need to run `apt upgrade && apt update` instead of `apt update && apt upgrade`?

Answer (score 24):

for me, running `pkg upgrade && pkg update` has solved the problem

Comment: That just gives me a ton of "404 not found" errors in Termux...

Comment: @Cerin the main Termux package repo is experiencing issues. Try using `termux-change-repo` to switch to the GitHub mirror.

Comment: @NoahSherwin Yep, that was the issue. Default repo was missing.

Comment: Correct order is update and then upgrade.

Answer (score 11):

Orrr... just

```
pkg update openssl-tool
```

or

```
apt update openssl-tool
```

Is the same.

;)

Comment: Should you override /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/tls/openssl.cnf when running this command?

Comment: @BrandonRos I did it. It works and didn't break anything. So, yes you should.

Answer (score 7):

The google play version of Termux is deprecated.

Installing from Fdroid has solved this problem for me.
https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 6):

You can also try changing the default repo mirror.

Run the following command:

```
termux-change-repo
```

This will drop the shell to an options window allowing you to select an alternative mirror. Once you have selected one, Termux should then run pkg update or apt update on its own.

For me, this solved pretty much all package related issues.

I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use git but faced with the same issue. These commands helped in my case. Source: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/11331#issuecomment-1193137080

```bash
pkg upgr
pkg i openssl-1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

For me upgrading through `pkg upgr` worked.

This will update packages, then during installation there will be `Y/N/I` type prompt, whether to `upgrade` or not. I added all `Y`.

And lastly `ssh-keygen -b 4096` generated key in home. However key is small

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is very simple.
Upgrading solved the issue

```bash
apt upgrade
```